# MVC 5 Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I  two views named, Index and Child and i have added child on index as a partial view. both views have two separate controllers. I want to call a method on child controller from a button click on Index page partial child. Ajax calls are working for methods written in index controller. but not the child controller.

Comment: can you show your code and explain what you are seeing when you say it isn't working on the child controller?

Comment: I was able to achieve this by inheriting child from parent(Index) :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by inheriting child controller from parent controller.

Comment: Could you add some code so that others (like myself) can benefit from your solution?